# Facebook app invite cannot select friend

Tags: ios, facebook-invite-friends

I have updated the iOS Facebook SDK to the latest version (v4.8.0) and I have implemented the [app invite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/ios) feature. It is working, but I have encountered an issue on the invite friends screen. There is the list of friends (Recommended Friends and Other Friends), I cannot select the first friend from the Recommended Friends list, and selecting/deselecting other friends is problematic.

If I go back to the previous screen on which I can add a message to the invite then press next to select the friends, everything is ok, I can select/deselect anybody with no issue.
The invites are being sent which is ok, I have just this problem that could be annoying.

Has anybody else encountered this issue?

Comment: Give us more details: provide code, provide a screen shot, tell us whether this happens on iPhone (which) or iPad (which), in the simulator or on a real device, exactly which parts of the screen seem to be non-responsive...

Comment: No iPad, only iPhone any kind (did not test on 4S but if it is happening on iPhone 5/5S, 6, 6+ I think it is happening on every type), both devices and simulator.This is the screen I am talking about, http://imgur.com/ufjtQgy and the first time the user enters this screen, he cannot tap on the first person in the list.

Comment: You haven't shared code yet. Also please provide details of your window/view controller/view hierarchy.

Comment: If you were to look in the documentation of the functionality from Facebook, you would see that you do not have control on what's happening on the screen that I have provided earlier, the only code is:  FBSDKAppInviteContent *content =[[FBSDKAppInviteContent alloc] init];
        content.appLinkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://fb.me/xxx"];
        // present the dialog. Assumes self implements protocol `FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate`
    [FBSDKAppInviteDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];